# How can I reproduce a database context to debug a tricky PostgreSQL error: "variable not found in subplan target list"

Tags: postgresql, debugging, dump

I am facing a tricky error with a PostgreSQL Database that suddenly popped up and I cannot reproduce elsewhere.

The error happened suddenly without any known maintenance or upgrade and seems to be related to a specific database context.

### Documentation

The bug seems to go back and forth, here is a list of links found when searching over the web for the error message:

- Februray 2015: [How to fix "InternalError: variable not found in subplan target list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126845/how-to-fix-internalerror-variable-not-found-in-subplan-target-list)
- October 2017: [query error: variable not found in subplan target list (when using PG 9.6.2)](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/235)
- Feburary 2022: [PGroonga index-only scan problem with yesterday’s PostgreSQL updates](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4c347490-d734-5fdd-d613-1327601b4e7e@mit.edu)
- June 2022 (my report): [Sudden database error with COUNT(*) making Query Planner crashes: variable not found in subplan target list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/VI1PR09MB438296EF87338CF6606F03FEE7A29%40VI1PR09MB4382.eurprd09.prod.outlook.com)

The product version I have detected the error is:

```
SELECT version();
-- PostgreSQL 13.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit
```

And the only extensions I have installed are:

```
SELECT extname, extversion FROM pg_extension;
-- "plpgsql"    "1.0"
-- "postgis"    "3.1.1"
```

### Symptom

The error main symptom is **variable not found in subplan target list**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items;

-- ERROR:  variable not found in subplan target list
-- SQL state: XX000
```

And does not affect all tables, just some specific ones.
What is interesting is that it is only partially broken:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM items;  -- 213

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE id > 0; -- 213
```

And it only affect the `COUNT(*)` aggregate most probably because of the `*` placeholder.

Further more the error is related to the query plan not to the query itself as:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item;
-- ERROR:  variable not found in subplan target list
-- SQL state: XX000
```

Fails as well without actually executing the query.

Digging into the PostgreSQL code on GitHub the error message appears [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ce4f46fdc814eb1b704d81640f6d8f03625d0f53/src/backend/optimizer/plan/setrefs.c#L2967-L2972) and is related to the function [`search_indexed_tlist_for_var`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ce4f46fdc814eb1b704d81640f6d8f03625d0f53/src/backend/optimizer/plan/setrefs.c#L2636) in case it returns nothing.

This pointer should explain why it happens when using `*` placeholder instead of an explicit column name.

### Reproducibility

It is a tricky bug, simply because showing it exists is difficult and the bug is somehow vicious as by now I cannot understand which conditions make it happen.

It seems this bug is raising in specific context (eg. bug with equivalent message and symptom reported with the [`PGroonga` extension](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4c347490-d734-5fdd-d613-1327601b4e7e%40mit.edu)) but in my case I cannot make a parallel by now.

It is likely I am facing an equivalent problem in a different context but I could not succeed in capturing a simple MCVE to spot it.

```
CREATE TABLE t AS SELECT CAST(c AS text) FROM generate_series(1, 10000) AS c;
-- SELECT 10000

CREATE INDEX t_c ON t(c);
-- CREATE INDEX

VACUUM t;
-- VACUUM

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t;
-- 10000
```

Works as expected. Table having the issue relies on `postgis` extension index, but again I cannot reproduce it:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- CREATE EXTENSION

CREATE TABLE test(
    id serial, 
    geom geometry(Point, 4326)
);
-- CREATE TABLE

INSERT INTO test
SELECT x, ST_MakePoint(x/10000., x/10000.) FROM generate_series(1, 10000) AS x;
-- INSERT 0 10000

CREATE INDEX test_index ON test USING GIST(geom);
-- CREATE INDEX

VACUUM test;
-- VACUUM

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test;
-- 10000
```

Works as expected.

And when I dump and restore the faulty database the problem vanishes.

### Looking for a MCVE

When trying to reproduce the bug in order to build an MCVE and unit tests to highlight it and report it to developers I face a limitation. When dumping the database and recreating to a new instance, the bug simply vanishes.

So the unique way I can reproduce this bug is using the original database but I could not succeed to prepare a dump of the database to reproduce the bug elsewhere.

This what it is all about, I am looking for hints to reproduce the bug in my context.

At this point my analysis is:

- The bug is related to the database state or to some meta data that is not equally the same when the dump is restored;
- The bug is related to the `COUNT` function when using the `*` wildcard when there is no filtering clause;
- The bug is not general as it affects only specific tables with specific index;
- The bug reside at the query planner side.

Seems like some meta or state corruption prevent the query planner to find a column name to apply the `COUNT` method.

### Question

My question is: How can I deeper investigate this bug to make it:

- either reproducible (a dump technique preserving it);
- or understandable to a developer (meta queries to identify where the problem resides in the database)?

Another way to phrase it would be:

- How can I reproduce the context which is making the query planner crashes?
- Is there a way to make the planner more verbose in order to get more details on the error?
- What queries can I run against the catalog to capture the faulty context?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126845/how-to-fix-internalerror-variable-not-found-in-subplan-target-list

Comment: @Kadet I am aware of this post. My question is not about finding a workaround. My question is about documenting this bug to make it reproducible or understandable.

Comment: I think bug is already documented  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4c347490-d734-5fdd-d613-1327601b4e7e%40mit.edu
And there are steps to reproduce it in first post